# Pyramid conditional execution of views based on from where the view is being called

Tags: jquery, python-2.7, pyramid

I have a project based on Pyramid framework. There is a new requirement where, for certain views I have to perform certain pre-check before calling those views.

Basically the scenario is, say if i have a tabbed pane implementation in UI with three tabs, tab A, tab B and tab C. The requirement is, while moving from tab A to tab B i should pop up a message to user asking confirmation "If you really want to move to tab B" but the same is not required while i move from tab C to tab B i.e. when i move from tab C to tab B there should not be any such message.

PS, I am using ajax calls in JavaScript to call views.

I am not sure as where and how to handle this, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rapid solution if there is no dynamic logic to it: just hardcode it in the HTML. If there is some logic, you can compute in view and pass to templates, then render in HTML. If it gets more complicated, you probably can do something with events.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the views where the pre-check is required into a single handler and then have an **init** for that handler that does the required pre-check.

You could create a pre-check decorator that you apply to all the views that require it.

You could do as Antoine Leclair suggests and handle it all client-side with javascript or in template logic if there's nothing dynamic in the pre-check.

The way I see it you want your pre-check to determine whether or not this pop-up message requirement is needed. So the end result could be a boolean variable like: message_required.
Then, in your template you could do a check like:

```
%if message_required:
    //message logic here
```